# Update group of rows to delete a specific total amount from the sum of the rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

In example I want to subtract the `Subtracted` value in `TABLE 1` from the Sum Total of the `ValueBefore` in Table 2 grouped by the `GroupID`. Value subtracted from first row and if remainder then that is subtracted off the following row in group (and so on) until total is subtracted.

Is there a way to do this without iterating through rows to get the remainder?

My table 1:

```
TABLE 1 of subtracting value
GroupID    Subtracted
  1          32
  2          30
```

My table 2:

```
ID   GroupID     ValueBefore     Reduction      ValueAfter   
 1     1             10            -10             0
 2     1             15            -15             0 
 3     1              5             -5             0 
 4     1              5             -2             3
 5     2             40            -30            10
 6     2             30              0            30
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, other?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 - sorry see my tags did not capture that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a cumulative sum and some relatively simple comparisons:

```
select t2.*,
       (case when t2.running_value - t2.valuebefore < t1.subtracted
             then 0
             when t2.running_value < t1.subtracted
             then t2.running_value - t1.subtracted
             else t2.valuebefore
        end) as reduction,
       (case when t2.running_value < t1.subtracted then 0
             else t2.running_value - t1.subtracted
        end) as ValueAfter
from (select t2.*,
             sum(valuebefore) over (partition by groupid order by id) as running_value
      from t2
     ) t2 join
     t1
     on t2.groupid = t1.groupid;
```

Comment: Slightly different than what I needed, but the Over clause solved it.
The above keeps incrementing the ValueAfter, where I needed that to equal the ValueBefore if there is nothing more to subtract. Need another when clause at start of ValueAfter of
"when t2.running_value - t1.subtracted > t2.valuebefore then t2.valuebefore"

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a `LEFT JOIN` in order to calculate the running total of `ValueBefore`.

This query:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t2.GroupID, t2.ValueBefore, r.ValueBefore AS rValueBefore       
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS r 
   ON t2.GroupID = r.GroupID AND t2.ID >= r.ID
ORDER BY t2.ID, r.ID
```

produces this output:

```
ID  GroupID ValueBefore rValueBefore
------------------------------------
1   1       10          10
2   1       15          10
2   1       15          15
3   1       5           10
3   1       5           15
3   1       5           5
4   1       5           10
4   1       5           15
4   1       5           5
4   1       5           5
5   2       40          40
6   2       30          40
6   2       30          30
```

You can now calculate the running total if you group by `ID` and `SUM` on `rValueBefore`:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t2.GroupID, t2.ValueBefore, SUM(r.ValueBefore) AS Total      
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS r 
   ON t2.GroupID = r.GroupID AND t2.ID >= r.ID  
GROUP BY t2.ID, t2.GroupID, t2.ValueBefore
```

**Output:**

```
ID  GroupID ValueBefore Total
-----------------------------
1   1       10          10
2   1       15          25
3   1       5           30
4   1       5           35
5   2       40          40
6   2       30          70
```

You can now calculate `ValueAfter` using:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.GroupID, t.ValueBefore, Total,
       Subtracted,
       CASE 
          WHEN Total - t1.Subtracted  < 0 THEN 0 
          ELSE Total - t1.Subtracted
       END AS ValueAfter
FROM 
(
   SELECT t2.ID, t2.GroupID, t2.ValueBefore, SUM(r.ValueBefore) AS Total      
   FROM Table2 AS t2
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS r 
      ON t2.GroupID = r.GroupID AND t2.ID >= r.ID  
   GROUP BY t2.ID, t2.GroupID, t2.ValueBefore
) as t
JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t.GroupID = t1.GroupID
ORDER BY ID
```

**Output:**

```
ID  GroupID ValueBefore Total   Subtracted  ValueAfter
------------------------------------------------------- 
1   1       10          10      32          0
2   1       15          25      32          0
3   1       5           30      32          0
4   1       5           35      32          3
5   2       40          40      30          10
6   2       30          70      30          40
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c33dc/11)

Comment: I can see this working well in versions of SQL where Over clause is not available. Thanks for suggestion.